# Location of Pod config on Workernode

Tags: kubernetes

Are there any locations where I can see all pod's configuration scheduled on that workernode?

I would like to run some static checks on each worker nodes using Ansible to check if the pod's have been given enough resources (CPU/MEM), I have to explicitly run this job on worker node only and not through kubectl API call.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can try below command

```
crictl stats
```

if you are using docker as runtime then replace crictl with docker

[image]

Comment: Thanks but this still doesn't give me the resources allocated to container (Requests/Limits)

Answer (score 0):

This command can be executed from any node or from a system which has access to the cluster. It gives the pods in  all namespaces deployed in a particular node.

```
kubectl get pods -A -o wide --field-selector spec.nodeName=<nodename>
```

This will list all pods from all namespaces but you can narrow it down for specific namespace by the following command.

```
kubectl get pods -n ns -o wide --field-selector spec.nodeName=<nodename>
```

Replace ns with required namespace.

For requests and limits

```
kubectl describe nodes <node name>

kubectl get pods -o yaml
```

you can see the pods running on the node and their cpu and memory requests and limits.

Answer (score 0):

Requests are only relevant during scheduling, while limits are also relevant for the container runtime, Therefore, we can find the limits on a worker node, but not the requests. Running `crictl inspect` on a container and selecting the relevant JSON object, gives us the following output:

```
$ crictl inspect <container-id> | jq "[ .status.labels, .info.config.linux.resources]"

[
  {
    "io.kubernetes.container.name": "my-container",
    "io.kubernetes.pod.name": "my-pod",
    "io.kubernetes.pod.namespace": "my-namespace",
    "io.kubernetes.pod.uid": "12c6cc6a-563c-11ed-b133-8b3c7e21ebf0"
  },
  {
    "cpu_period": 100000,
    "cpu_quota": 50000,
    "cpu_shares": 51,
    "memory_limit_in_bytes": 536870912,
    "oom_score_adj": 995,
    "hugepage_limits": [
      {
        "page_size": "2MB"
      },
      {
        "page_size": "1GB"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

The values do perfectly fit the limits as defined in my pod definition (see https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/resource_constraints/ for an explanation of `cpu-period` and `cpu-quota`).

```
resources:
  limits:
    cpu: 500m
    memory: 512Mi
  requests:
    cpu: 50m
    memory: 32Mi
```